# equivalent list comprehension in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, list-comprehension, tensor

How can I modify a tensor of rank 1 containing N int to a tensor of rank 2 containing N vector of size M with a dictionary

in python something like:

```
dict = {1 : [1,2,3] , 2 : [3,2,1]}
array1 = np.array([1,1,2,1,2])
array2 = np.array([dict[x] for x in array1])
```

but I cannot iterate over a Tensor (aside from while loop but I don't think it's the optimal solution)

Answer (score 3):

If the dict you have is something like

```
dict = {1: tf.constant([1, 2, 3]), 2: tf.constant([1, 2, 3])}
tensor1 = tf.constant([1, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

then something like this should do the job:

```
vals = [dict[tensor1[k]] for k in range(tensor1.get_shape().as_list()[0])]
tensor2 = tf.stack(vals, axis=0)
```

It becomes more complicated if you have unknown dimensions. For instance, I don't see solutions that don't involve tf.while_loop if the shape of tensor1 is unknown.

Comment: I guess I am missing something I get error KeyError: <tf.Tensor 'my_name/strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int64>

Comment: I get TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.