# Using list comprehensions in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, list-comprehension

Can we use Python comprehension in Tensorflow graph (non eager) execution?

```
IOU: tf.Tensor = tf.concat(            
    values=[
        intersection_over_union(
            box_pred[..., j, 1:5],     
            box_true[..., 1:5]         
        )
        for j in range(self.B)         # <--- predicted boxes
    ],
    axis=-1,
    name="IOU"
)
```

I think Graph cannot have a loop by default and need to use either `@tf.function` or `tf.while_loop` but some posts used comprehension, hence would like to confirm.

[equivalent list comprehension in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284477/equivalent-list-comprehension-in-tensorflow)

```
vals = [dict[tensor1[k]] for k in range(tensor1.get_shape().as_list()[0])]
tensor2 = tf.stack(vals, axis=0)
```

Comment: Do u face any error?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I suppose you know TF graph does not support loop, so there are tf.function or while_loop. Does TF automatically recognize comprehension and convert to tf.cond or tf.while_loop when parsing Python-specific logic in order to become part of the graph? If you know how TF graph parsing handles comprehension, please provide an answer?

Comment: No, that wouldn't even be *possible*. The list comprehensions evaluates to a list object before it is passed to the function. tensorflow isn't even involved here.

Comment: so, there is no loop here, as far as tensorflow is aware. There is a *list object* which gets passed to `tf.concat` or `tf.stack`

Comment: ```for j in range(self.B)``` is the loop and I am not sure how this loop in comprehension will be evaluated by Tensorflow to convert the code to it graph. If you know how Tensorflow handles Python built-in comprehension, kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is the case. I provide a code below doing it:

```
# tested on TF 2.13.1
import tensorflow as tf
        
@tf.function
def list_comprehension(l):
    return tf.concat([tf.reshape(ll, (1,-1)) for ll in l], axis = 0)
l = [tf.random.uniform(shape=[5,2]) for _ in range(6)]

print(list_comprehension(l).shape)
# output (6, 10)
```

I define a list having tensors of shape (5,2). In the function I change the shape of each one of them and concatenate them along axis 0.

If list comprehension is hard to trace, is there a solution without using list comprehension? Something closer to TF ops and more optimized?

I am asking this question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77475224/tensorflow-graph-mode-effective-reshaping-of-tensors-in-a-list).